# How do I properly escape the single quote in node-postgres queries?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I need to execute the following query:

```sql
db.query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name ILIKE '%$1%';", [ query ])
```

It seems like node-postgres doesn't replace the `$1` parameter and I don't know why. My query works if I change the line to:

```sql
db.query(`SELECT * FROM items WHERE name ILIKE '%${query}%';`)
```

But now I have problems when the query contains single quotes (`'`).

Should I replace all single quotes using regex (as in `query.replace(/'/g, "''")`) (I don't think that's recommended)?

Otherwise, how can I get node-postgres to accept my parameter? I think it has something to do with the encapsulating `%` symbols. I keep running into the same problem with this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your placeholder isn't replaced because `'%$1%'` is an SQL string literal that just happens to look like it contains a `$1` placeholder. You can add the percents in JavaScript using string operations:

```
db.query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name ILIKE $1", [ `%${query}%` ])
// ---------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or in SQL using SQL's string operations:

```
db.query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name ILIKE '%' || $1 || '%'", [ query ])
// --------------------------------------------^^^^^^----^^^^^^
```

Comment: Great, that was it. Just one of those little things that aren't really documented anywhere.